# Windows Server Core System Tray

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, bittorrent, windows

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 Core on my machine. I use BitTorrent Sync to synchronize and backup my valuable Documents. But I want to add another Folder-pair, for which I need to access the System Tray since BitTorrent Sync resides there.

How do I access the System Tray? or How do I access the Application?

Answer (score 2):

Server Core does not have a system tray or a task bar on which to put a system tray.

If you *have* to use the system tray, then re-enable the GUI with `Install-WindowsFeature`.

Alternatively, you could find whatever registry or ini file values that the application is modifying when you fiddle with the system tray, and simply replicate that action via command line methods.